# Two scopes with the same :as in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-5

I have some rails 3 routes that worked perfectly, for versioning an API with different module:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  scope module: :v2, constraints: Constraints::ApiVersion.new(versions: [2, 2.1], default: false) do
    scope 'feedback/:id' do
      get 'summary', controller:'summary', action: 'summary', as: 'response_summary'
    end
  end

  scope module: :v1, constraints: Constraints::ApiVersion.new(versions: 1, default: true) do
    scope 'feedback/:id' do
      get 'summary', controller:'summary', action: 'summary', as: 'response_summary'
    end
  end
end
```

But now in rails 5, I get this error:

> Invalid route name, already in use: 'response_summary'  (ArgumentError)
>   You may have defined two routes with the same name using the `:as` option, or you may be overriding a route already defined by a resource with the same naming. For the latter, you can restrict the routes created with `resources` as explained here: 
>   http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#restricting-the-routes-created

Is there anyway to keep the `:as` the same in Rails 5?

Comment: if you call `response_summary_path` it will always route to v2 so changing v1 shouldn't affect your app.

Comment: @kasperite Are you saying that because the path will both be the same regardless, it doesn't matter what the `:as` is?

Comment: pretty much, named routes are read top down so the first one will always be selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I change `v1` to have a different `:as` it seems like the path stays the same, as @kasperite pointed out.

```
response_summary     GET   /feedback/:id/summary(.:format)  /v2/summary#summary
response_summary_v1  GET   /feedback/:id/summary(.:format)  /v1/summary#summary
```

`response_summary_path` and `response_summary_v1_path` path will be the same it seems like

```
2.5.1 :017 > response_summary_v1_path(5)
 => "/feedback/5/summary" 

2.5.1 :018 > response_summary_path(5)
 => "/feedback/5/summary"
```